# Implementing a support ticket/help desk system?

Tags: drupal, extension

I would like to implement a support ticket or help desk system through the CiviCRM. This way, all support requests and email responses are tracked in the CiviCRM as well as who handled it, or who it gets assigned to, whether it's open or closed, etc. I read that CiviCase could be modified to make this happen, but we also have several different types of support we need to provide and want to know what all my options are.

What would be the best way to make this happen?

Drupal 7.50 CiviCRM 4.7.15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could involve CiviCase, but depending on your needs you may get away with just creating custom Activity Type(s) and custom Activity Statuses. And then given you are doing this in Drupal, I would spin it all together via Webform+CiviCRM which should then give you ability to have a single form and apply Conditionals based on the 'need' to specify which Activity Type, Priority (as a new custom field on Activities) and Target contact.

hth

Answer (score 1):

I'd be thinking towards doing it all in Drupal. Keeping CiviCRM for the CRM data - only. It's easier to make things look nice in Drupal and support ticket data are not CRM type data - they are of a more transient nature.

Comment: I know what you mean but I need something specifically for CiviCRM for staff to use, internally.

Comment: I know what you mean - but I'd still go Drupal :-) Leverage the abilities of your CMS.